# How can I generate traffic from trace file in mininet?

Tags: traffic, mininet, iperf

I have trace file name dec-pkt which have 6 columns as follow:

- timestamp of packet arrival.

For the first packet in the trace, this is the
raw tcpdump timestamp.  For the remaining
packets, this is the offset from the integer
part of that first timestamp.

For example, if the first timestamp is 187.2, the
second is 188.9, and the third is 191.3, then
the first three timestamps in the ASCII file will
be 187.2, 1.9 (= 188.9-187), and 4.3 (=191.3-187).

Note that sanitize-syn-fin uses as its base time
the arrival of the first TCP packet in the file,
not the first TCP SYN/FIN/RST packet (this helps
when comparing sanitize-syn-fin times with those
produces by sanitize-tcp).

- (renumbered) source host
- (renumbered) destination host

  Note that the renumbering process loses any IP network
  information.
- source TCP port
- destination TCP port
- number of data bytes in the packet, or 0 if none (this
  can happen for packets that only ack data sent by the
  other side)

So I wonder how can I generate this traffic using this file? can Iperf
do that? if not how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate traffic easily via Scapy. It also comes with Mininet VM which you can find in mininet official website. It can generate packet for both TCP and UDP.

Here is an example  python code. You can find more on Github or Scapy's official tutorial.

```
import sys
import getopt
import time
from os import popen
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import sendp, IP, UDP, Ether, TCP
from random import randrange


def sourceIPgen():
    not_valid = [10,127,254,1,2,169,172,192]

    first = randrange(1,256)

    while first in not_valid:
        first = randrange(1,256)

    ip = ".".join([str(first),str(randrange(1,256)),str(randrange(1,256)),str(randrange(1,256))])

    return ip


def gendest(start, end):

    first = 10
    second =0; third =0;
    ip = ".".join([str(first),str(second),str(third),str(randrange(start,end))])
   # print start
   # print end
    return ip

#if __name__ == '__main__':
  #main()

def main(argv):
   # global start 
   # global end
    print argv
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'s:e:',['start=','end='])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt =='-s':
            start = int(arg)
        elif opt =='-e':
            end = int(arg)
    if start == '':
        sys.exit()
    if end == '':
        sys.exit()


    interface = popen('ifconfig | awk \'/eth0/ {print $1}\'').read()

    for i in xrange(1000):
        packets = Ether()/IP(dst=gendest(start,     end),src=sourceIPgen())/UDP(dport=80,sport=2)
        print(repr(packets))

        sendp( packets,iface=interface.rstrip(),inter=0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

[Referance](https://github.com/Anandkumar26/DDOSAttack_SDN/blob/master/Python%20Code/launchTraffic.py)

And you can call it like

```
python ./launchTraffic -s 2 -e 28
```

Comment: This is uselessly complicated ! You have some Linux only system calls completely useless and you could use scapy’s `Net()` generator for the IPs

Comment: I did not write this code as I mentioned. It is not that complicated and it can easily convert.

Comment: Not against you, for instance sourceIPgen could be re-written as one line:
`str(RandIP(iptemplate="%s.0.0.0/8" % random.choice([x for x in range(256) if x not in [10,127,254,1,2,169,172,192]])))`

Comment: As I said, I just referance a link which I did not write, but I used. He/She can change it. It is not main answer for this question.

Comment: I know it's a bit too late to say, but Thank you. I did check about Scapy but I don't get a point at this code. I thought this code "sendp( packets,iface=interface.rstrip(),inter=0.1)" means send 1 packet but how come there's interval there?